# Getting around "Protocol X can only be used as a generic constraint"

Tags: swift

I'm working on a form-input library. My goal is to have a re-usable set of validators which can be applied to a set of form fields. I'm running into difficulty specialising my generic protocol. The full error from the code below is `protocol 'FieldValidator' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`.

Complete playground-ready code:

```
import Foundation

protocol FieldValidator {
  associatedtype InputType: Any
  func validate(input value: InputType)
}

struct EmailValidator: FieldValidator {
  func validate(input value: String) {}
}

enum Field {
  case string(_: [FieldValidator])
  case integer(_: [FieldValidator])
}

let emailField: Field = .string([EmailValidator()])
```

**What I've tried**

I understand that in the `Field` enum I can't just throw in a `FieldValidator` because it needs to know what `InputType` of validator it requires. I expect that I need to tell it somehow, maybe something like this:

```
case string(_: [FieldValidator<String>])
case integer(_: [FieldValidator<Int>])
```

or this:

```
case string(_: [FieldValidator where InputType == String])
case integer(_: [FieldValidator where InputType == Int])
```

but these doesn't work. Is there a way to keep this kind of architecture?

*Edit using `struct` instead of `enum` for field types:*

```
struct StringField {
  typealias InputType = String
  let validators: [FieldValidator]
}
```

I still appear to have the same problem defining the set of validators (which must be provided when the Field is initialised): `protocol 'FieldValidator' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`.

Comment: Call me dense, but I'm not grasping what the enum is _for_.

Comment: It's just the way I chose to define the different types of fields available. It also is used to determine the type of value passed into and retrieved from the form field. It could be a series of structs, I suppose: struct StringField, struct IntField.

Comment: @matt I have had a quick go of using a struct or class rather than an enum, but I had no luck with either of those. Is there a better option?

Comment: I still haven't understood what you're trying to do. There are an _infinite_ number of types of fields available. InputType is unrestricted, so anyone can adopt FieldValidator and resolve InputType as anything at all. I don't see where the notion of "string-or-int" comes from or how it relates to your use of a generic here.

Comment: I realise in the original code that InputType is unrestricted. I figured that was actually the source of the error: the compiler doesn't know what type the FieldValidator expects because of the associated type requirements. I also figured that there was a way I could tell the compiler what type to expect, through something like `<Type>` or `where InputType == Type`. I suppose what I'm trying to do is provide a mechanism by which someone can define a Field, define what type of value it holds, and define a set of reusable Validators which will operate on that value and determine if it's valid.

Comment: Okay, I think I see the problem. You'd need to use some sort of type erasure if you want to say "an array of FieldValidator adopters that resolve InputType to String".

Comment: I've provided an alternative solution that doesn't require us to use type erasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suppose what I'm trying to do is provide a mechanism by which someone can define a Field, define what type of value it holds, and define a set of reusable Validators which will operate on that value and determine if it's valid

You might be after something like this; it's stupid but effective, especially if there are not very many field types in question:

```
protocol FieldValidator {
    associatedtype T
    func validate(input:T)
}

class StringValidator : FieldValidator {
    func validate(input:String) { fatalError("must override me") }
}

class IntValidator : FieldValidator {
    func validate(input:Int) { fatalError("must override me") }
}

class ActualStringValidator : StringValidator {
    override func validate(input:String) { print(input)}
}

enum Field {
    case string([StringValidator])
    case int([IntValidator])
}
```

As you can see, I've simply used the class hierarchy to solve the problem (so that we don't have to do type erasure). In particular, it is now legal to say:

```
let f = Field.string([ActualStringValidator()])
```

Here's how to test it:

```
let f = Field.string([ActualStringValidator()])
if case Field.string(let arr) = f {
    for thing in arr {
        thing.validate(input:"howdy")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works just fine. Shame about `class` but at least it does the job nicely. I found it's possible to define the enum as `case string([FieldValidator<String>])` and then `ActualStringValidator` can just inherit `FieldValidator<String>` without needing to have an intermediary.

Comment: It is a shame about `class` for sure, but I'm fairly certain that the struct approach would have require type erasure, which is a little hairy. If you want, I'll try to work out that solution (but I'd rather not).

Comment: Happy not to! Thank you